# Hue configuration error

Tags: hadoop, configuration, oozie, hue

At the start of hue it shows error in Oozie configuration shows

" Share Lib not installed in default location."

Default location given is 
 `/user/oozie/share/lib`

But in my system it is given at
`/user/amandeep/share/lib`

How can change it. Please help

Comment: I looked through the Hue code and it doesn't appear to be configurable.  You could possibly change it in Hue's code at "desktop/libs/liboozie/src/liboozie/conf.py".  See : https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/libs/liboozie/src/liboozie/conf.py

Is there any reason you cannot put it in the default location?

Comment: thanks  @brandon.bell ... but at the time of using commad ` ./oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000/user/oozie ` it transfers it to  ` /user/amandeep/share/lib` .. is there any way to resolve it.

Comment: Try running it as `oozie` user.  `$ sudo -u oozie ./oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000/user/oozie`

Comment: tried that but not helping ..